# How to create a "live" icon like in Mac OS with the red circle in its top corner?

Tags: ios, linux, windows, macos

I wonder, is it possible to create an icon or widget or whatever it'll be in Linux or Windows so it'll act like icons in Mac OS in Dock or OSX  in the sense that it'll show the red number of something (unread messages, usually) in its top corner when some even occurs. If yes then how?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.  You'll need to do more research on user interface programming, notifications, and adding API's on an OS-specific basis.  Then come and ask questions about your specific implementation choices.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your mean is Badge Number ?

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:4];

Comment: No. The question is asking how to mimic this on *other* operating systems.